# Probability at least 1 element is in its correct spot

Tags: probability

Given a list of length $n$, with elements $1$ though $n$ in a random order. What is the probability that at least one element $x$ is at position $x$?

**For example**

In the list $5, 2, 4, 3, 1$ ($n=5$)

The element $2$ is at position $2$.

**Furthermore**

What is the probability as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Comment: Hint:  look up [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: You are asking about the probability of the complementary event to *no element is in its correct spot*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *lulu* and *hardmath* pointed out, this the complementary event to *no element is in it's correct spot*.

### The probability

Which means the probability that at least one element is in it's correct spot is going to equal:
$$p(n)=1-\frac{[\frac{n!}{e}]}{n!}$$

Where $[x]$ is the *nearest integer function.* (Could probably be cleaned up a bit.)

### The limit

According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), the limit as $n$ aproaches infinity converges to the following.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}p(n)=1-\frac{1}{e}$$